# Two mutable borrows from vector

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I am following a tutorial on breakout game written in rust and I have simple data structure representing balls on the screen:

```
pub struct Ball {
    rect: Rect,
    vel: Vec2,
}
```

It is stored in vector

```
let mut balls: Vec<Ball> = Vec::new();
```

However when I try to calculate ball to ball collision I encounter error:

```
 --> src/main.rs:193:31
    |
192 |         for ball in balls.iter_mut() {
    |                     ----------------
    |                     |
    |                     first mutable borrow occurs here
    |                     first borrow later used here
193 |             for other_ball in balls.iter_mut() {
    |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
```

```
// ball collision with balls
        for ball in balls.iter_mut() {
            for other_ball in balls.iter_mut() {
                if ball != other_ball {
                    resolve_collision(&mut ball.rect, &mut ball.vel, &other_ball.rect);
                }
            }
        }
```

My initial approach was to use double iteration, now I know that borrow checker wont allow me to modify vector as it is considered unsafe. Is there a common pattern that I could use to solve this kind of issues?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `split_at_mut`. It feels a bit hacky, but works OK. Here's an implementation that gets two *different* mutable values.

```
pub fn get_mut2<T>(v: &mut [T], i: usize, j: usize) -> Option<(&mut T, &mut T)> {
    if i == j {
        return None;
    }
    let (start, end) = if i < j { (i, j) } else { (j, i) };

    let (first, second) = v.split_at_mut(start + 1);
    Some((&mut first[start], &mut second[end - start - 1]))
}

pub fn main() {
    let mut data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
    let (a, b) = get_mut2(&mut data, 3, 6).unwrap();
    *a += 10;
    *b += 10;
    eprintln!("{:?}", data); // [0, 1, 2, 13, 4, 5, 16, 7]
}
```

There's a working version on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=41e21bdb8fdc4fe6ad8d84eb8fbb669e).

You'd then need a double loop over your array lengths:

```
assert!(!a.is_empty());
for i in 0..a.len()-1 {
  for j in i..a.len() {
    let (ball_i, ball_j) = get_mut2(&mut a, i, j).unwrap();
    ...
  }
}
```

Note that my loop ensures I only visit each unordered pair once.

Comment: I think for the need expressed here a prettier version is to split and return the value at `i` *and the `i+1..` slice* to the caller. A bit of a variant on the `split_first`/`split_last` functions: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f9dcec9a2c18995c7857534b03ff4466 it would even make sense to bundle that as a tails-type iterator, but doing that in Rust has a bit of overhead due to the lack of generators.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RefCell` for mutability and `iter()` instead of `iter_mut()` so that compiler won't complain that the code borrows the vec twice, e.g.:

```
struct Ball(u32, u32);

let mut balls = vec![];

balls.push(RefCell::new(Ball(0, 0)));
// push more balls into vec

for b1 in balls.iter() {
    for b2 in balls.iter() {
        // change attributes of a ball
        b1.borrow_mut().0 = 10;
        b2.borrow_mut().1 = 20;
    }
}
```

Comment: In this example the loop body has b1 and b2 pointing to the same RefCell for some iterations.  This code is _lucky_ since the borrow ends at the end of each line. From the docs if you try to have two references into the same RefCell you get a panic. So this loop body is very restricted, it could not be `f(b1.borrow_mut(), b2.borrow_mut)`.

Comment: Yes I understand. Although `borrow_mut()` will panic at runtime if a previous borrow exists, instead of compile-time failure. `f(b1.borrow_mut().deref_mut(), b2.borrow_mut().deref_mut())` will pass compilation. It's up to the program to check that `b1` and `b2` are different balls before calling `f()`. The code is for demo.